# Angular2 issues retrieving URL parameters

Tags: angular, typescript, query-string

I am currently implementing a confirm email process in my angular 2 application (.net core 2 backend). The workflow currently goes: user registers -> they are sent an email to confirm their account -> they click the link -> they're directed to an angular component that SHOULD read the userId and generated token. The Url in the browser is `http://localhost:35000/confirm-email?token=CfDJ8OR7TVlXC69LsUgYal539cq4%2FcxvIXYoyaXcvLXQofMfK8d%2Bp6JE02IBATC49meM8bNSq9pgzq%2B7MspZLt7h1hfetLF2iVkXRkQZHFiJluhRpJbZ7kkafpyrbXjs82KFjkzVSOEDGV4sC6x4%2Bd0i0SXejfK%2F%2FpZgKTnOhdvB%2FwbLK5iauwdDXnjV7ZN7LHA0HInpvBPF2OOpdjJ%2FXicRLYLq5ic4Pz7SnXz0iwOTj4HJQIZAX%2FA1DqgvrPR6vuaOwQ%3D%3D&userId=5da26d4c-f737-481c-9142-affd89e8e9d6`

which routes me to the confirm-email component below however I am unable to read my params `token` and `userId` properly - they are always undefined. The simplified code for my angular component is below:

```
export class ConfirmEmailComponent implements OnInit {
    emailConfirmed: boolean = false;

    constructor(private userService: UserService,
        private router: Router,
        private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
          let token = params['token'];
          let userId = params['userId'];

          this.userService.confirmEmail(token, userId).subscribe(
            (data) => {
              this.emailConfirmed = true;
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please console.log(params) and show us the result? Thank you

Comment: @GianlucaParis it is an empty array `{}`

Comment: Also your route path should be defined as: path: 'confirm-email/:token/:userId', is it right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to subscribe to `activatedRoute.queryParams`, not `params`, obviously, as you pass data through query parameters, not predefined params ('my-url?key=value' instead of 'my-url/:someParam'). Just like this:

```
this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe((params: Params) => { //etc
```